# Capturar elemento web desde APP Winforms C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms

estoy intentando hacer una aplicación que haga lo siguiente:
Dentro de un proyecto WinForms con un webrowser, exactamente CefSharp (Chrome).
Necesito hacer que una vez dado a un botón web, capture la URL donde te envíe ese botón web. La web también la tendría que hacer yo por lo que no hay ningún problema de compatibilidad y también para daros más información.

No pongo ningún código por que no tengo ni idea de como se hace ni como empezar, he estado buscando pero lo único que encuentro es para hacer que por ejemplo al clicar un button de la APP genere un evento para clicar al button web y cosas similares.

Lo que necesito es que capture la URL del botón web, aunque también me serviría que capturara la id del botón por que las URL son todas iguales y solo cambian un par de numeros al final y si genero eso en la APP + el id del botón ya me serviría, aun que prefiero la otra forma.

Muchas Gracias!

Comment: A que te refieres con capturar la url?,   como es la pagina que haras?

Comment: Utilizare HTML, si veo que no tengo mucho tiempo alomejor la hago con worldpress, lo mas seguro que sea con WP